# What does "Run the packager with `--clearCache` flag" mean in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I always use `react-native run-ios` to run my React Native apps, but when debugging it suggested "Run the packager with --clearCache flag". What does this mean? What is the packager, and how do I run it with the "--clearCache flag?"

Answer (score 5):

A React Native app is a compiled app that is running some Javascript. Whenever you build and run your React Native project, a packager starts up called Metro.

The packager does a few things:

1. Combines all your Javascript code into a single file, and translates
   any Javascript code that your device won’t understand (like JSX or
   some of the newer JS syntax).
2. Converts assets (e.g. PNG files) into objects that can be displayed
   by an Image component.

For React Native Init approach (without expo) use:

```
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

Or you can use:

```
react-native start --reset-cache
```